# Зачем создавать многомодульный maven проект?

Tags: maven, java

Народ, объясните неопытному. Изучаю JavaEE месяц уж третий в рабочих условиях. Сразу кинули без теоретической базы на создание небольшого проекта на работе. Сперва было EJB + Jboss, потом сборка maven-ом, а теперь и GWT. Столкнувшись с последним, испытал немалые трудности со сборкой. А вот щас только мне открыли весь модель основного проекта и до меня доходит осознание темы топика. Изначально я стал в любимой IDEA собирать многомодульные проекты. Не помню уже с чего началось - то ли с тем как показали быстро на примере в Eclipse, то ли еще с чего. Но проектики собирались maven-ом и даже все таки удалось к моим добавить проект в gwt. И вот гляжу я на наш рабочий проект, который делал не я, а там один модуль со структурой для gwt-web приложения и куча пакетов. Так вот ответьте мне на вопрос, когда нужно использовать multiply module-project, и зачем?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю смысл многомодульного проекта в том чтобы пересобирать артифакты совместно.
Если вопрос почему бы не сложить всё в один большой артефакт, то ответ для логической декомпозиции.

Мне случалось видеть, когда один подпроект собирал jar c ресурсами, второй генерировал код с jaxb аннотациями из xsd, а основной тем временем собирал обычный рукописный исходный код.